# SQL Spatial number of times a Linestring intersects other Linestrings

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

So, I have a table named "lines" that has a field named "WKT" with the corresponding geography.

I builded a query that gives me the name of the line that was intersected, like this:

```
DECLARE @DF GEOGRAPHY  
Set @DF=GEOGRAPHY::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-9.564498 52.237100,-9.564906 52.243924,-9.565699 52.245563,-9.568173 52.251014,-9.567142 52.257567,-9.564291 52.262366,-9.563453 52.262972,-9.563447 52.262980,-9.563447 52.262980,-9.563447 52.262980)', 4326)  
select name, @DF.STIntersects(WKT) AS inters
from lines WHERE @DF.STIntersects(WKT)=1
```

And it works very well. The problematic case is when this @DF line is a "go and return by the same path". In this case I wanted to know the names of the repeated lines that were intersected.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Assuming that you've got a tally table (i.e. a table with numbers 1 through some large number):

```
DECLARE @DF GEOGRAPHY  
Set @DF=GEOGRAPHY::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-9.564498 52.237100,-9.564906 52.243924,-9.565699 52.245563,-9.568173 52.251014,-9.567142 52.257567,-9.564291 52.262366,-9.563453 52.262972,-9.563447 52.262980,-9.563447 52.262980,-9.563447 52.262980)', 4326)  

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT n, @DF.STCurveN(n) AS curve
    FROM dbo.Numbers
    WHERE n <= @DF.STNumCurves()
)
select name, @DF.STIntersects(WKT) AS inters
from lines AS l
JOIN cte AS c
    ON l.WKT.STIntersects(c.curve) = 1
```

I'm sure that you could get away without using the CTE, but that was what made the most sense in my head.

Comment: At the first approach I never thought that the SQL version could be an issue, but after investigating on your reply, I found that STNumCurves() only works on SQL Server 2012 and I'm using SQL Server 2008 (not possible to upgrade)... Do you think that this could be obtained by another method?

Comment: Maybe. Looking at the list of methods available in 2008 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933917%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the closest we have is `STGeometryN()` and `STNumGeometries()`. You could make those work if you are willing to define @DF as a MULTILINESTRING instead of a LINESTRING. It's kind of a pain to convert one to another; right now the linstring def looks like a → b → c whereas the multilinestring would be a → b, b → c, but the two definitions should be equivalent.

Comment: Long story short: there were significant improvements in 2012 to spatial. If you have the option to use that, do it.